# Kde plasma blank with mouse cursor

Tags: kde, plasma5, kde-neon

Since I have upgraded kde plasma my desktop won't start showing me a blank screen with mouse cursor in tty1.

According to some searches I have tried to solve the problem with updating and upgrading using these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

I'm using kde plasma 5.15.3.

So any suggestion to solve,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to affect various users (including me!), but owing to the complexity of KDE/Plasma etc. it's not an easy fix. Some people get a blank screen, and nothing more, others just have the case of the GUI session taking forever to eventually load the desktop. Rather than having to manually load your X session each time, also try the following:

1. Try setting the permissions of `~/.config` to `775` or even `777`, via

   ```
   chmod g+rwx ~/.config -R
   ```

   for the former, `a+rwx` for the latter.
2. Also try resetting the ownership of all the `~/.config` files to the correct local user, as some users reported issues with files owned by root after an upgrade. Use

   ```
   chown user.user ~/.config -R
   ```
3. Some users also found that removing all the KDE config files worked for them, so try:

   ```
   mkdir ~/temp
   mv ~/.kde ~/temp/.kde
   ```

   or if you get an error:

   ```
   mv ~/.kde* ~/temp/.kde
   ```

   ```
   mv ~/.cache ~/temp/.cache
   mv ~/.local ~/temp/.local
   mv ~/.config ~/temp/.config
   ```

   And then reboot or restart the login manager, and try again. You can then manually copy back whatever app settings you need from `.config` or `.local` to get back your personal settings. It's a pain, but it has worked for some.
4. Also try a dist-upgrade instead of a plain upgrade (as @MohamedSlama reported in the original question!). Follow the howto for your distro... but basically it's recommended to get a terminal login and goto init 3 (kill graphical login) and then from a root screen session, issue the dist-upgrade command. Then see if it comes right.
5. In my case, openSuse Leap 42.3 upgrade to 15.1, a dist-upgrade didn't work either. I had to move from the stable Leap 15.1 to Tumbleweed to get things going... but I did work on another machine, with the same issue, and traced the issue to the plasmashell. This has historically given me issues, and I often reset via a script that runs

   ```
   kquitapp plasmashell && kstart plasmashell &
   ```

Comment: #3 works very well if you have made a lot of customizations to themes, etc. and the theme has been uninstalled by upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after i have searched for a long time i found a simple alternative solution.

1. Open tty2 by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **+** <kbd>Alt</kbd> **+** <kbd>F2</kbd>.
2. Enter username.
3. Enter password.
4. Write command `startx`.

Comment: If this is the solution, then it means you have no graphical login manager installed/running after the upgrade. Also, a manual startx like this may not work as expected on modern distros. Additionally, note that this is not a solution if X is already running, but just broken... as X will refuse to start, unless you specify a different screen session. Go well.